# how do i get the raycast to destroy the game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to destroy the object you shoot but when ever i shoot nothing happens

```java
     void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
            {

                if (Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, 500))
                {

                    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking if the Raycast hit something. You can do it like this

```
    void Update()
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
       {

         Raycasthit hit;

         if(Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position,cam.transform.forward,out hit,500))
         {
            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
         }
       }
    }
```